# Turn Multiple Rows into 1 Column with Multiple Fields in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table that looks like this in `Teradata SQL Assistant`:

```
Software Name   Employee
Word            Bob
Excel           Bob
Word            Kim
Excel           Kim
PowerPoint      Bob
```

I want to create it so that for each software, there is only 1 row and each employee is stored as a binary 1 or 0 based on whether they have the software or not. The Final Table should look like this:

```
Software Name    Bob   Kim
Word             1      1
Excel            1      1
PowerPoint       1      0
```

I'm using `Teradata 15.10` and I haven't been able to figure it out how to do this because `Teradata 15.10` does not support the `PIVOT` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select software_name,
       sum(case when employee = 'Bob' then 1 else 0 end) as Bob,
       sum(case when employee = 'Kim' then 1 else 0 end) as Kim
from t
group by software_name;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon.